# HEAT liberated in mechanical processes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, work, collision

[image]

Can we calculate heat liberated without changing our frame, in the situation of sand [from rest] falling on a moving conveyer belt maintained at steady speed.

And in question in picture, how is that heat is released as it is like an elastic collision between small particle entering tube and similar one leaving tube in horizontal direction. Is the thought of elastic collision wrong?

Comment: Ok but i asked if it is possible to solve without changing frame (first case). In second case answer given was (c,d).

Comment: The easiest way to solve without changing frame (second case) is to use energy considerations (kinetic/potential). The outcome of such an analysis (I can provide it as an answer if you wish) is that c is the correct answer;  d is incorrect.  Without friction, there will be no heating.

Comment: In the first case, it can be solved without change of frame by focusing on the interface between the sand and the belt as a massless entity that receives work and releases an equal amount of heat.  I seem to remember a problem with a block with friction on a belt on this forum, in which I provided an answer for a laboratory frame.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557737/why-is-heat-energy-dissipation-in-two-intervals-frame-dependent

Comment: It took me a while, but I figured how to solve this ropes-in-a-tube problem using force balances as well as by the mechanical energy balance method.  It was very challenging.

Comment: Is D correct ?,and please add answer also.

Comment: Please Kindly answer

Comment: D is NOT CORRECT.  I'm writing in my answer now for the energy balance approach.  It will be there soon.

Comment: It's ok if D isn't correct

Comment: Work-K.E. equation gives answer as C which is valid if D is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the energy balance approach:

Since friction with the tubular structure is negligible and the inertia (mass) of the tubular structure is negligible, the sum of the kinetic- and potential energies of the ropes must be constant.

As the tubular structure descends, the total length of the vertical sections of rope is constant, and their total potential energy (determined by their combined mass distribution above any arbitrary datum) does not change.  Also, their velocities at any time are zero.  So their kinetic energies do not change.  So only the kinetic- and potential energies of the horizontal section(s) of rope within the tubular structure change.

Let z represent the vertical location of the horizontal section at any time and let m represent the mass of rope within the horizontal section.  So the potential energy of the mass of rope in this section is just PE=mgz.

The downward vertical velocity of the horizontal section of structure and the rope within it is $v=-\frac{dz}{dt}$.  During the time interval dt, the length of the upper vertical section of rope increases by vdt, and the length of the lower vertical section of rope decreases by vdt.  In order of this to happen (and conserve mass), rope must pay out of the horizontal section of tubing with the same velocity v; and it must enter from the lower portion of vertical rope at the same velocity v.  So the horizontal velocity of the rope within the horizontal section of tubing must also be v.  So the rope within the horizontal tubing must have both horizontal and vertical velocity components equal to v.  And thus, the kinetic energy of the rope within the horizontal tubing must be $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=mv^2$The total mechanical energy of the horizontal section of ropes is given by $$KE+PE=mv^2+mgz$$And the rate of change of this total energy must be zero:  $$2mv\frac{dv}{dt}-mgv=0$$So the downward acceleration of the tubular structure and rope within it is given by $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{g}{2}$$